# Fetching message as well as image from json file in js

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am new to JavaScript, and also json. I've created a code in which I want to fetch the message, as well as image, from json file. I am able to fetch the messages, but I'm not able to fetch the image.

I've given URL of image in json file.

Here is my js code:

```
fetch('http://localhost/chats.json').then(function(response){
      return response.json();
      console.log(response.json());
    }).then(function(json){
          console.log(json);

        json.message.forEach(function(item){   

        var li=document.createElement("li");
        var img=document.createElement("img");

        img.src=item.url;
        img.width="100px";

        var text=document.createTextNode(item.msg);
        li.appendChild(text); 
        li.appendChild(img);

        document.getElementById('line').appendChild(li);
        $("ul>li").each(function(i,val){
          $(this).css("color",i & 1? "#FF8000" : "#8080C0");
        })

      })
    }).catch(function(error){
      window.alert('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
    })
```

And here is my json file:

```
{ 
  "message":
    [
      { 
        "user": 1,
        "msg_id":1,
        "msg": "Hello, how are you?",
        "url": "http://placehold.it/600/6dd9cb"
      }
    ]
}
```

Edit-1 Here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="container div" style="position: absolute;">
    <h2 class="panel-heading out" style="margin-right: 50px;">User1</h2>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-body"> <ul id="line" style="list-style: none; font-family: Helvetica Neue"><img id="image_li"></ul> </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Might be helpful to see your html

Comment: sure i'll update it right now @MattSpinks

Comment: The code looks fine. What does not work?

Comment: it is not showing images where my messages are @Bergi

Comment: So it's showing the messages just fine?

Comment: yes its showing only messages but not images @Bergi

Comment: Do your devtools show any error messages? What can you see in the network panel?

Comment: it shows "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)" @Bergi

Comment: Hm weird, but then yes that server is your problem. Can you see the image if you load it manually, or can you see it when used on other pages?

Comment: change `img.width = "100px";` to `img.width = "100";` or `img.style.width = "100px";` - https://jsfiddle.net/L974ygeq

Comment: i can see the image if i insert the url in src of image. But when i fetch it , its not showing @Bergi

Comment: Thanks. It is showing the block of image,but not the image @JaromandaX

Comment: the jsfiddle I linked to shows the image - any messages/warnings/information in the browser **developer** tools console? is your site https perhaps?

Comment: No the link u've given is not showing the image.The developer tool looks fine,no error. Just i can't read network panel of developer tool. I'm running it on apache2 @JaromandaX

Comment: no the link I gave is showing a 600x600 image scaled to 100x100 by the width attribute of the img tag

Comment: `i can't read network panel of developer tool. I'm running it on apache2` - you should run the browser developer tools console to see what the browser is getting, not sure what "apache2 network panel of developer tool" is

Comment: as i told I'm very new to all this things.Of course,"your link is showing the block for image but not the image"-that's i want to say.
Console of my chrome browser is showing nothing and i've stored the file in apache2 @JaromandaX

Comment: the fiddle shows the image - if you don't get the image the problem is with your browser or your network

Comment: @VaibhavMandlik `http://placehold.it/600/6dd9cb` doesn't look like an URI for a file on your apache server

Comment: if u want i can give the pic of developer tool @JaromandaX

Comment: so what can i do now @Bergi

Comment: @JaromandaX first of all I'm really sorry. I thought it was showing just a block but it was the image. And very very thanks to you for your help. I'm really sorry and thank you from bottom of my heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct answer which shows the image. Thanks to user:5053002.

```
 var json = { "message":
[
  { 
    "user": 1,
    "msg_id":1,
    "msg": "Hello, how are you?",
    "url": "https://placehold.it/600/6dd9cb"
  }
]};   json.message.forEach(function(item) {

var li = document.createElement("li");
var img = document.createElement("img");

img.src = item.url;
img.width = "100";

var text = document.createTextNode(item.msg);
li.appendChild(text);
li.appendChild(img);

document.getElementById('line').appendChild(li);
$("ul>li").each(function(i, val) {
    $(this).css("color", i & 1 ? "#FF8000" : "#8080C0");
})   })
```

Thank You – Jaromanda X